# Weird Build issue with Intellij, Maven, Scala pulgins

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, spark-submit

I am facing really weird build issue with Intellij, Maven and Scala.

We have scala project, when I package it into jar by running mvn clean, mvn scala:compile and mvn install or package, it generates jar file perfectly but when I deploy this jar to our AWS EMR ec2 instance and when I run that jar with spark-submit command sometimes it complains about

> "Error: Failed to load class com.OUR_PACKAGE_NAME.ScalaMainClass"

So I tried to check my code which looks perfectly fine, it complies fine, also it runs fine in my local machine. But sometimes that same generated jar works fine and sometime it does not in AWS EMR ec2 instance. It is not consistent.

So I reverted back my code to previous working stage and started adding my code one by one untill I get this "Failed to load class" problem. Then I encounter that one of the scala class having some issue. Visually code looks fine also it compiles great, but somehow that scala class creates problem when mvn creates jar file and when we run it to EC2.

The weird part is that, when I hit enter and add new blank line before or after problematic line of code, maven generated jar works fine. So I believe there is some hidden character which maven does not like or intellij is not able to uncode properly. And when I takeout that blank line that error appears again.

Could you help me on that?

Comment: This sounds quite unlikely but please copy paste us the code which generates the problem versus the code that does not?!

Comment: Can you download back the JAR from EC2 and see what it contains? Compare with the local JAR..

Comment: I find out it is deployment error to spark cluster, while deployment our process had bug which makes jar corrupt by removing some of bit in transit. I find out when I extract the jar file and my Main class was missing also deployed jar size was off by few bits as well. After deploying manually to cluster it worked.